# All drivers disabled after reinstallation

Tags: grub2, usb, mouse, touchpad, mbr

I've been running Ubuntu 12.04 for quite a while, but after installing Windows XP onto another partition, the MBR was overwritten, etc etc.

I downgraded 12.04 to 11.10 using a Live CD, but it still didn't work. Used `boot-repair` then reinstalled 11.10, and I got GRUB back. Yes!

So, I booted Ubuntu, and found that I had no control over anything except the keyboard. The touchpad, USB mouse, disk drive, USB anything, wireless card, all gone. This naturally means that I can't get anything onto the hard drive without lots of shenanigans using the Live CD.  I've got a Gateway W340UI.

Eager to get 12.04 back.

Comment: In my opinion, your solution that upgrade 12.04 to 11.10 is really bad idea to recovery grub menu. In this case, grub possible to recovery just using Boot-Repair (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) on ubuntu live-cd.

Comment: I know now.  It's a MiRaClE that I still have my files intact.  Sadly, I was mangling it before I looked at my problem well.  Ugg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by booting to an older kernel (3.0.0.23), which recognized my drivers, and then installing Ubuntu 12.04 from there.  Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: For the benefit of others who have similar problems, do you know what older kernel you used? If so, you can edit your answer to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open Terminal.

Run `lsmod` to check your drivers one by one.

My other recommendation is to re-install your Ubuntu system. (Or if your network works fine via Ethernet, then you can try to upgrade to newer kernel versions, either now or after reinstalling.)

Comment: Okay...  I have at least fifty drivers listed while in Live Boot, but when booting off the hard drive, I have four.  uas, usb_storage, pata_atiixp, and sky2.